# XCode NSIntegerv return memory leak after analysis

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsinteger

I have this code which created with `UITableView` and making the cell's color show alternatively white and grey. [image: Capture]

How can I correct this, without memory leak? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using ARC or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_white.png"]];
```

This leaks the `UIImageView`. You allocated it, but you didn't release it afterwards.

To fix:

```
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_white.png"]]; 
cell.backgroundView = imageView;
[imageView release];
```

The arrows in the analyzer warning are a little misleading -- they're trying to show the flow of the execution through the code, into the method that caused the leak, and then out. The textual messages are the important part.

(Also, I suspect you want `tbl_RowIndex1 % 2`, not `tbl_RowIndex1 %= 2`.)